# Unexpected behaviour when pattern matching with Longest

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, language-design, function-comparison

I came across some unexpected behaviour today when using the `Longest` function when trying to do some pattern matching.

```
StringCases[#, a___ ~~ b_ ~~ Longest[c___] ~~ b_ ~~ d___ -> {a, b, c, d}] &@"abcbba"
```

The intent is to find the two identical characters which are the furthest apart in the string.
I would expect this to return `{a,b,cb,a}`, since that would be the longest possible distance between two identical characters. However, it instead returns `{abc,b, ,a}`. I don't understand why it's not finding the longer possibility, especially when default behaviour when matching patterns seems to be that earlier patterns try to match the shortest possible sequences. Using `c__` instead of `c___` makes the behaviour more like the expected behaviour for this case, but I do want the pattern to work when the only sets of identical characters are adjacent to each other.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a number of subtle details at work here.  Perhaps the prominent one is that in string expressions, unlike expression patterns, `Longest` and `Shortest` do not actually refer to the maximal or miminal possible match in a string.  Rather, they correspond to the regular expression concepts of [greedy and ungreedy](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#SEC17).

**Furthest Apart Identical Characters?**

The question states that the intent is to find the two identical characters that are furthest apart in the string, and that the expected answer is `{a,b,cb,a}`.  However, the characters that actually meet this criterion are the two a's at the ends of the string, which should yield a result of `{,a,bcbb,}`.  This is a consequence of the observation that the subpatterns `a___` and `d___` are permitted to match empty strings.  However, we do not get this result.  Why?

The reason is that the initial subpattern is "greedy", meaning that it will match the maximal number of characters that does not cause the overall pattern to fail.  We can see this is so from the actual result obtained: `{abc,b,,a}`.  The pattern `a___` has greedily matched `"abc"`, leaving only the remnant `"bba"` for the rest of the pattern to match.  The leftover adjacent b's become our paired characters.

We do not want `a___` to be greedy, so we use `Shortest[a___]`:

```
StringCases["abcbba",
  Shortest[a___] ~~ b_ ~~ Longest[c___] ~~ b_ ~~ d___ -> {a, b, c, d} ]

(* {{,a,bcbb,}} *)
```

`Shortest` is the string pattern syntax to make a repetition "ungreedy" (also sometimes known as "reluctant" or "lazy").  Ungreedy repetition matches the *minimal* number of characters while still giving the rest of the pattern a chance to succeed.

The use of `Longest` here is redundant since it is the default:

```
StringCases["abcbba",
  Shortest[a___] ~~ b_ ~~ c___ ~~ b_ ~~ d___ -> {a, b, c, d} ]

(* {{,a,bcbb,}} *)
```

If we change the subject string so that it does not start and end with the same character, we get a result very much like the one desired by the question:

```
StringCases["abcbbz",
  Shortest[a___] ~~ b_ ~~ c___ ~~ b_ ~~ d___ -> {a, b, c, d} ]

(* {{a,b,cb,z}} *)

StringCases["123bcbb45",
  Shortest[a___] ~~ b_ ~~ c___ ~~ b_ ~~ d___ -> {a, b, c, d} ]

(* {{123,b,cb,45}} *)
```

**How does all this relate to regular expressions?**

*Mathematica* string patterns are a high-level expression-based syntax that is [implemented using PCRE](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html#337819047), a [regular expression engine](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/).  The concept of [greediness](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#SEC17) comes from that engine.

We can see how `Longest` and `Shortest` compile down to regular expressions:

```
StringPattern`PatternConvert[a___] // First

(* "(?ms)(.*)" *)

StringPattern`PatternConvert[Longest[a___]] // First

"(?ms)(.*)"

StringPattern`PatternConvert[Shortest[a___]] // First

"(?ms)(.*?)"
```

Close inspection shows that `Shortest` changes the regular expression from `.*` to `.*?`.  The trailing `?` is the regular expression syntax to turn off greediness.

The PCRE notion of greediness does *not* have anything to do with whether a match is the overall longest or shortest possible match within a string.  Rather it controls whether a repeating pattern will consume the maximal (greedy) or minimal (ungreedy) number of characters *without causing the rest of the pattern to fail* (if possible).  Subject to this behaviour, scanning proceeds from left to right.  The first valid match is always used unless the remainder of the pattern fails.  Such failure causes backtracking to try other possible matches.

The following examples demonstrate that extreme pattern lengths are not a consideration for string patterns:

```
StringCases["0111011110", Shortest["1"..]]
(* {1,1,1,1,1,1,1} *)

StringCases["0111011110", "1"..]
(* {111,1111} *)

StringCases["0111011110", Longest["1"..]]
(* {111,1111} *)

StringReplace["0111011110", Longest["1"..] :> "x"]
(* 0x0x0 *)
```

Observe how the presence of `Longest` does not restrict its operation to the absolute longest match.  Also observe that since none of our patterns used `StartOfString`/`EndOfString` to anchor to the string ends, multiple matches are possible.

**Why are Longest/Shortest different between string and expression patterns?**

In contrast to string patterns, expression patterns *do* have a notion of the absolute longest match:

```
{0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0} /. {___, Longest[x : 1 ..], ___} :> {x}

(* {1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

Also, for expression patterns the default is `Shortest` instead of `Longest`:

```
{0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0} /. {___, x:1.., ___} :> {x}
(* {1} *)

{0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0} /. {___, Shortest[x:1..], ___} :> {x}
(* {1} *)
```

Why are there such differences?

The different defaults are due to history.  *Mathematica* has used `Shortest` as the default for expression patterns from the beginning.  String patterns were added relatively recently, and they follow the default convention that virtually all regular expression engines have adopted.

As for the semantic differences, history is still a factor but there are two other significant reasons as well.

First of all, repeating expression patterns can only work on sequences.  Sequences are not quite first class citizens as they are always hosted within a full expression "container".  Patterns must match the containers that hold sequences instead of the sequences themselves.  This is illustrated by the `/.` examples above.  Once such a container has been matched or replaced, further scanning within that container stops.  Strings have no such notion of "container", so string patterns are under no such restriction.  This "container" behaviour means that expression patterns are always anchored in some sense.  Very recently, version 10.3 introduced functions like `SequenceCases` to loosen these restrictions a little.

Second, there is the matter of practicality.  String patterns are based upon PCRE.  PCRE has no notion of the longest overall match.  Therefore neither do string patterns.

**A good design decision?**

On account of the semantic differences, one might argue that the names `Longest` and `Shortest` were misleading choices for the string pattern syntax.  Perhaps they should instead have been something like `Greedy` and `Ungreedy`.  That would at least suggest to a reader that they have different semantics.  But the differences are subtle and there is always pressure to resist adding new symbols to the system namespace (`*Data` symbol notwithstanding).  A design choice was made, and it is defensible.  Hindsight is 20/20.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I guess the reason I would say I disagree with the design decision is because it's the opposite of the design decision for pattern matching in lists, for example
`{a, b, c, d, e, f, g} /. {x__, y__, z__} -> {{x}, {y}, {z}}` returns `{{a}, {b}, {c, d, e, f, g}}`, with the earlier patterns matching minimal elements of the string.

Answer (score 8):

Is this what you want?

```
StringCases[#, StartOfString ~~ Shortest[a___] ~~ b_ ~~ c___ ~~ b_ ~~ 
     Shortest[d___] ~~ EndOfString -> {a, b, c, d}] & /@ {"abcbba", "abccde"}

(* {{{"", "a", "bcbb", ""}}, {{"ab", "c", "", "de"}}} *)
```

remember that `StringCases[ ]` matches **substrings**, not complete strings

---

Or perhaps:

```
StringCases[#, 
   StartOfString ~~ a___ ~~ b_ ~~ c___ ~~ b_ ~~ d___ ~~ EndOfString -> 
           {a, b, c, d}, Overlaps -> All] & /@ {"abcbba", "abccde"}

(* {
   {{"abc", "b", "", "a"}, {"a", "b", "cb", "a"}, {"a", "b", "c", "ba"}, 
                                                  {"", "a", "bcbb", ""}},    
   {{"ab", "c", "", "de"}}}
```

Comment: While this does solve the issue, I'm more looking for an explanation of why the above expression evaluates the way it does. Could it be considered a bug, for instance?

Comment: @ASimmons The explanation is my last sentence. See the last element of `StringCases["abcbba", 
 a___ ~~ b_ ~~ Longest[c___] ~~ b_ ~~ d___ -> {a, b, c, d}, 
 Overlaps -> True]`

Comment: @dr-belisarius I'm not sure I understand your explanation. Regardless of the fact that it's matching substrings, it's failing to produce the longest `c___` that matches the pattern. Additionally, the paradigm you've suggested wouldn't work if I wanted to retain the whole of the string's information, and it would be good to have an expression that did.

Comment: @dr-belisarius you've addressed the second part of my post with your edit but I can't remove it from the comment; disregard that bit.

Comment: @ASimmons Perhaps you'll get it better with this one `StringCases[s, 
 StartOfString ~~ a___ ~~ b_ ~~ Longest[c___] ~~ b_ ~~ d___ ~~ 
   EndOfString -> {a, b, c, d}, Overlaps -> All]`. The last one is the one you're after

Comment: BTW String matching ALWAYS defaults to `Longest[ ]`

Comment: If you try `StringCases["abcde",a__~~b__~~c__->{a,b,c}]`, you see that the initial patterns are matched minimally. It still puzzles me why in the example in the OP, `a___` is being matched maximally.

Comment: @ASimmons `StringCases["abcde", a__ ~~ b__ ~~ c__ -> {a, b, c}]` returns `{{"abc", "d", "e"}}`. So the `a__` is acting greedy, as one should expect. Perhaps I don't understand you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't actually have mathematica to hand when I wrote that. I guess the issue is that it contrasts with expressions like

`{a, b, c, d, e, f, g} /. {x__, y__, z__} -> {{x}, {y}, {z}}`

which returns `{{a}, {b}, {c, d, e, f, g}}`. Obviously this isn't string matching but it seems strange the patterns work out so differently.
I guess you've answered my question by saying that all string matches default to `Longest`- but that seems unhelpful for patterns like mine above where there's a clear priority.

Comment: @ASimmons You certainly could use Regexes. `a___` is equivalent to `(.*)` and `Sortest[a___]` is `(.*?)` . You may get the conversion by using ``RegularExpression[StringPattern`PatternConvert[YourStringPattern]]``