# What kind of pattern should I use with StringCases?

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

Consider the string

```
str = "ABCaDEFbcABCdefDEF"
```

I'd like to take out all substrings surrounded by the substrings `"ABC"` and `"DEF"`; that is, I want to pull out

```
(* {a, def} *)
```

If I could just get the substrings

```
(* {ABCaDEF, ABCdefDEF} *)
```

then I could easily remove the unwanted capital letters with `StringTrim`.

In order to do this, `StringCases` looks like my best bet, but I'm not sure what kind of pattern to use. `Blank` isn't right because it only gives me one of the desired substrings:

```
StringCases[str, "ABC" ~~ _ ~~ "DEF"]
(* {ABCaDEF} *)
```

On the other hand, `BlankSequence` gives me too much:

```
StringCases[str, "ABC" ~~ _ _ ~~ "DEF"] (* space added for emphasis *)
(* ABCaDEFbcABCdefDEF *)
```

What kind of rule can I use to get what I need?

**Added**: One thing I've considered is reversing the pattern to look for:

```
StringCases[str, "DEF" ~~ _ _ ~~ "ABC"]
(* {DEFbcABC} *)
```

followed by `StringSplit`

```
StringSplit[str, %]
(* {ABCa, defDEF} *)
```

and finally `StringTrim` to get

```
StringTrim[StringTrim[%, "ABC"], "DEF"]
(* {a, def} *)
```

Are there any better ways of going about this?

**Edit 2**: My attempt does not work for longer strings, however.

```
strNew = "ABCaDEFbcABCdefDEFghijABCklmnoDEF";

StringCases[strNew, "DEF" ~~ _ _ ~~ "ABC"]
(* {DEFbcABCdefDEFghijABC} *)

StringSplit[strNew, %]
(* {ABCa, klmnoDEF} *)
```

which doesn't include the substring containing `def`. Looks like Marco's suggestion to use `Shortest` is the clear winner.

Comment: In your second attempt, have you tried `Shortest[__]` instead of just `__`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
StringCases["ABCaDEFbcABCdefDEF", "ABC" ~~ Shortest[a__] ~~ "DEF" :> a]

(* Out: {"a", "def"} *)
```

Comment: I don't think I've ever used `Shortest` before so I'll need to check the documentation to fully grasp it, but this seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @user170231 With regard to using `Shortest` and `Longest` in string patterns you should read this lengthy but vital post by WReach: [(108399)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108399/121)