# Partitioning string into longest substrings of given characters

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I want to partition string into longest substrings that each contain only specific characters, beginning from left to right with no overlaps, always choosing the longest one possible at current position. In my example only substrings that contain only characters `d,f,g` or `d,e,h` or `a,b,c,g` are allowed.

Example:

input:

```
StringCases["ABCDEFGH",Longest[("D"|"F"|"G")..|("D"|"E"|"H")..|("A"|"B"|"C"|"G")..]]
```

output:

```
{"ABC","D","E","FG","H"}
```

But after `"ABC"` there is evidently substring `"DE"` that is longer than `"D"` or `"E"`.
So my expected output would be:`{ABC,DE,FG,H}`

If I switch first and second argument of `Alternatives` this way:

```
StringCases["ABCDEFGH",Longest[("D"|"E"|"H")..|("D"|"F"|"G")..|("A"|"B"|"C"|"G")..]]
```

then output is as expected:

```
{"ABC","DE","FG","H"}
```

But `Alternatives` should be from definition something that is independent on arguments order. So I would expect in both inputs the same output (second one).

**So my question is how to do it that I get always longest possible substring no matter what order of arguments inside `Alternatives` is?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do:

```
StringCases[
    "ABCDEFGH",
    Longest[p__] /; StringMatchQ[p,("D"|"F"|"G")..|("D"|"E"|"H")..|("A"|"B"|"C"|"G")..]
]
```

> {"ABC", "DE", "FG", "H"}

Comment: Yes, works as I wanted. But I hoped for a more efficient method. I can do it much faster using two nested `While` loops, taking character  by character till all of them belong to one set of characters. Anyway, I accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

> But `Alternatives` should be from definition something that is independent on arguments order.

`StringCases` is based on the PCRE regular expression engine for which [it isn't true](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108399/280): a regex engine [always returns the first match from listed in alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (when it allows to match the whole pattern).

To get the behavior you expected you should use `SequenceCases` instead (which doesn't use regexes and is based on *Mathematica*'s own pattern-matcher):

```
StringJoin @@@ 
 SequenceCases[
  Characters@"ABCDEFGH", 
      {Longest[("D" | "F" | "G") .. | ("D" | "E" | "H") .. | 
               ("A" | "B" | "C" | "G") ..]}]
```

> ```
> {"ABC", "DE", "FG", "H"}
> ```