# DeleteCases for once only

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I want to delete an array of elements from another one,
`DeleteCases` seems to be an option, but the problem is that it deletes an element more than once if available, I do not want this. I want to delete any element as many times as available in second list.

For example `DeleteCases[{1, 1, 2, 3}, Alternatives@@{1, 2}]` gives `{3}`, which means it deleted `1` twice from the first array. I want the output to be `{1, 3}`.
Is there any function other than `DeleteCases` which can do this?

Comment: If you want to delete the first case, then the output for your pattern would be `{1,2,3}` and not `{1,3}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing elements from a list which appear in another list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18100/removing-elements-from-a-list-which-appear-in-another-list)

Comment: Can you please address Jason's question?

Answer (score 14):

You can `Fold` the four-argument form of `DeleteCases`:

```
Fold[DeleteCases[##, 1, 1] &, {1, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}]
```

> {1, 3}

```
Fold[DeleteCases[##, 1, 1] &, {3, 1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 2}]
```

> {3, 1, 1}

To handle arbitrary number of lists as input we can `Fold` twice:

```
ClearAll[unsortedMultiSetComplement]
unsortedMultiSetComplement = Fold[Fold[DeleteCases[##, 1, 1] &, ##] &, {##}] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
unsortedMultiSetComplement[{1, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}]
```

> {1, 3}

```
unsortedMultiSetComplement[{3, 1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 2}]
```

> {3, 1, 1}

```
unsortedMultiSetComplement[{2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 2}, {2}]
```

> {3, 1, 5, 2, 2, 1}

```
unsortedMultiSetComplement[foo[c, a, c, a, a, b], foo[c, b], foo[b, b, a]]
```

> foo[c, a, a]

```
unsortedMultiSetComplement[foo[c, a, c, a, a, b], bar[c, b], buz[b, b, a]]
```

> foo[c, a, a]

Answer (score 10):

Another option which is based on an update:

Since `13.1` we have a new built-in arrow in our quivers called [**`DeleteElements`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteElements.html)

With the list of the OP

```
l={1, 1, 2, 3};
```

we simply write

```
DeleteElements[l, {1, 1} -> {1, 2}]
```

> [image: res]

The above is simply telling Mathematica to remove up to one instance of `1` and up to one instance of `2` from the list `l`.

Edit: many thanks to @lericr

In this example, the command can be written using the shorter

```
DeleteElements[{1, 1, 2, 3}, 1 -> {1, 2}]
```

Comment: Nice. Or `DeleteElements[{1, 1, 2, 3}, 1 -> {1, 2}]`.

Comment: @lericr Exatly! I just meant to do it as an update and brief explanation of the command. Will update to include yours as it's shorter :-)

Comment: Nice post, Indeed! :-)

Comment: @E.Chan-López thanks :-)

Comment: Hi mate @bmf, the ten ways to do this are ready :-)

Comment: @E.Chan-López just saw it. Awesome stuff :-)

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction) [MultisetComplement](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultisetComplement) to do this:

```
ResourceFunction["MultisetComplement"][{1, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}]
```

> {1, 3}

Comment: This will sort the target, however...

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's worth mentionning that `Replace` and `ReplaceAll` does the replacement only **once** *on the whole expression matching the pattern*.

So one can do this kind of thing :

`Replace[{1, 1, 2, 3}, {a___, 1, b___} -> {a, b}]`

> {1,2,3}

Notes :

- the default level specification for `Replace` is {0}
- "**once** *on the whole expression matching the pattern*" is intended to explain why `Replace[{1, 1, 2, 3}, 1 -> Nothing, {1}]`doesn't work.

Comment: `Replace[{1, 1, 2, 3}, 1 -> Nothing, {1}]` does work and returns `{2, 3}`, as expected. Probably you mean `Replace[{1, 1, 2, 3}, 1 -> Nothing]`, where the pattern doesn't match (as expected).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov In my answer, I mean : "doesn't work" to solve OP's problem. I totally agree that `Replace[{1,1,2,3},1-> Nothing]` works as expected. I will rephrase my answer this evening. By the way I'm not satisfied with the expression "Once ... pattern". If someone has a better and non ambiguous phrasing, I'm interested (I remember that I found even the documentation from Wolfram not clear about the scope of the word "Once". It was many, many years ago...)

Comment: It would be more correct to write "`ReplaceAll` apples a replacement rule only *once* on a (sub)expression matching the pattern, and never checks this (sub)expression for matching again." and remove mentioning of `Replace` from this statement, because `Replace` works differently: for example, check `Replace[{{},{}},{___}->1,{0,-1}]`. But I would remove this statement at all, because it isn't related to your answer. Regarding your answer, it is worth to say that `Replace` (unlike `ReplaceList`) returns only the result of the *first* possible match.

Comment: It is also worth to mention that [for expression patterns the default is `Shortest` instead of `Longest`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108399/280). This is crucially important for your solution.

Answer (score 5):

You may use `Tally` with `DeleteCases` in `Fold` to only fold once per value.

```
Fold[DeleteCases[#1, First@#2, 1, Last@#2] &, {1, 1, 2, 3}, Tally@{1, 2}]
```

> ```
> {1, 3}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Using `SubsetReplace`:

```
SubsetReplace[{1, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 2} -> Nothing, 1]
(*{1, 3}*)
SubsetReplace[{3, 1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 2} -> Nothing, 1]
(*{3, 1, 1}*)
SubsetReplace[{2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 2} -> Nothing, 1]
(*{3, 1, 2, 5, 2, 2, 1}*)
```

Or using `SubsetPosition` and `Delete`:

```
delElems[list_List, sublist_List] := 
Delete[list, Transpose@SubsetPosition[list, sublist, 1]]
(*Inspired by Syed's work*)
```

Examples:

```
delElems[{1, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}]
(*{1, 3}*)
delElems[{3, 1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 2}]
(*{3, 1, 1}*)
delElems[{2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 2}]
(*{3, 1, 2, 5, 2, 2, 1}*)
delElems[{{-1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}}]
(*{{-1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}}*)
delElems[{b, c, a, a, b, e, b, b, a}, {a, b}]
(*{c, a, b, e, b, b, a}*)
```

Now there are ten ways to do it.

Comment: Almost the 10 ways :-)

Comment: Nasser, Syed and Lericr soon join the party :-)

Comment: Hopefully they will :-)

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use explicit iterators in `Condition`:

```
Module[{n=1,k=1}, Replace[{1, 1, 2, 3, 2}, {1 :> Nothing/; n++ == 1, 2 :> Nothing/; k++ == 1},{1}]]
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 2}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

**Using `Delete`:**

```
delElems[k_List, del_List] := 
 Delete[k, 
  Flatten[#, 1] &@(Position[k, First@#, 1, Last@#] & /@ Tally[del])
  ]
```

**Usage:**

```
delElems[{1, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}]
```

> {1, 3}

```
delElems[{3, 1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 2}]
```

> {3, 1, 1}

```
delElems[{2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 2}]
```

> {3, 1, 2, 5, 2, 2, 1}

Comment: We were waiting for you. Kudos!

Answer (score 2):

use a counter solve this

```
cnt = {1,2} // Tally // Map[Apply[Rule]] // Association;
data = {1, 1, 2, 3};
Table[
  Which[
    KeyExistsQ[i][cnt] && cnt[i] > 0, cnt[i]--;, (*remove it*)
    KeyExistsQ[i][cnt] && cnt[i] === 0, Sow[i];, (*if needless to remove*)
    !KeyExistsQ[i][cnt], Sow[i];(*others*)
   ] 
 ,{i, data}
]//Reap//Last//First
```